# Can a BIOS be corrupted and the PC yet be functional?

Tags: bios

I went fiddling into the BIOS 2.14.1219 of my Asus UX31A laptop, wanting to enable network booting, to give it a test ride.
Except I did not fiddle with even one setting, as the BIOS boot menu was plain lacking items.
The items were not grayed out, they were not into a zone of the screen I forgot to check, as I triple-read each word from top-left to bottom-right, they were not just there,

in particular there was the classic

"Delete Boot Menu Item" - but its essential companion "Add Boot Menu Item" wasn't there.

I checked and triple-checked the security menu, no passwords are set. No one ever uses my computer, and no proficient computer user that knows what a BIOS and would perversely want to hack my computer for their own dark designs ever enters my home, only computer-illiterates.

Still it seems highly unlikely that a BIOS got corrupted in a way that yet permits complete and functional use of the computer. So what did I forget to triple-check?

Thanks a lot, this is perplexing!

Comment: Its very unlikely you BIOS would be corrupted AND your system would be stable and working.

Comment: Greyed out or missing features in BIOS means those features are not supported by that system.

Comment: It is impossible for your computer to work without working BIOS. BIOS is "Basic Input-Output System". Without the BIOS your computer would not be able to boot, and further more, would not be able to communicate with any hardware your computer has installed, so in short: No BIOS, no computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your BIOS does not support booting from a network.

If all BIOS supported boot options (from CD, from HD, from USB, ...) already were added to the boot order, then the BIOS would allow deleting these items but not allow adding an item because it does not make sense to put for example booting from HD at two places into the boot order list.

Comment: All right, as strange as it appeared to me, boot items are detected and added automatically, and there is never an "add item" option. Sorry for the fuss.

Comment: @puzzler If my theory is correct, then "add item" should appear when you delete an existing item.

Comment: Well, I scared me half to death for no reason, so I won't try it, now that it works as it should :)